# Old Intel Pentium PC: am I an i586? Does Gentoo provide i586 packages? What else am I compatible with?

Tags: linux, installation, cpu, gentoo, x86

Greetings Super Users!

I've recently commenced revitalizing a *very* old PC. She's running an Intel Pentium, x86_64. I thought I'd give Gentoo a go because I've found it very appealing and as a Bedrock user I wanted to be able to boot off of Gentoo's init system (initrc, we all know why) as well as bootloader. I've gotten almost halfway through the install ( maybe more like a third :))) ), and now I'm looking for the `stage3` files for my PC. I've noticed that though there are builds for `i486` and `i686`. Being genuinely interested in which my PC was, I searched it up and after some light digging found this explanation:

> - i386 works with any x86 processor (Intel, AMD,etc.),
> - i486 has some performance tun[n]ing.
> - i586 for Pentium and Pentium-MMX
> - i686 for Pentium-Pro, P2,P3, P4, etc.

[[source]](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/what-is-i486-i686-410580/#post2081265)

But in that case Gentoo doesn't support my device?!? Hence, my question: what `i` version (?) is my Intel Pentium PC? And where are the `stage3` files for it? Is it possible to use, say, an `i486` for a presumed `i586`?

Thanks in advance, bobbbay

EDIT: PC is the ol' [HP Pavilion Slim](https://support.hp.com/ca-en/document/c03791266).

Comment: Your CPU, the Pentium G2020, is an i686, it's from 2014 and based on the Core microarchitecture that came after the Pentium 4. The i586 Pentiums were from 1997 before the Pentium 2 came out!

Comment: @DavidSchwartz oh thank the Lord it's an i686, someone on retrocomputing (thanks for the hint btw @Moab) said I'd have to redo everything :)))) good to know, cheers! Feel free to post this as an answer here!

Comment: Please do not direct questions about modern computers, at most 7 years old, and how to run modern operating systems on them, to _Retrocomputing_, Moab.